# How do I implement this password class in my vb.net login form

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I came across this password class and I would like to use it in one of my projects. I have a Windows form that connects to a MySQL database. I have created the connection and was previously using this code to login to the system:

```vb
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Imports System.Net.Sockets

Public Class Login

'The maximum number of times the user can try to login.
Private Const MAX_ATTEMPT_COUNT As Integer = 3

'The number of times the user has tried to login.
Private attemptCount As Integer = 0
Dim adminLogin As Boolean


Private Sub OK_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles OK.Click


    Dim x As New System.Security.Cryptography.MD5CryptoServiceProvider()
    Dim bs As Byte() = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(TextBoxPassword.Text)
    bs = x.ComputeHash(bs)
    Dim s As New System.Text.StringBuilder()
    For Each b As Byte In bs
        s.Append(b.ToString("x2").ToLower())
    Next
    TextBoxPassword.Text = s.ToString()
    Dim pass = TextBoxPassword.Text

    If Me.ValidateCredentials Then
        Dim Obj As New Main
        adminLogin = False
        My.Forms.Main.RadTextBox1.Text = adminLogin
        Me.DialogResult = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK



    ElseIf Me.ValidateCredentials1 Then
        Dim Obj As New Main
        adminLogin = True
        My.Forms.Main.RadTextBox1.Text = adminLogin
        Me.DialogResult = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK


    Else
        Me.attemptCount += 1

        Dim message As String

        If Me.attemptCount = MAX_ATTEMPT_COUNT Then
            message = "The maximum number of failed logins has been reached." & _
                      Environment.NewLine & _
                      "The application will now exit."
            Me.DialogResult = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Abort
        Else
            message = "The provided credentials are incorrect." & _
                      Environment.NewLine & _
                      "Please try again."
            Me.TextBoxPassword.Clear()
            Me.TextBoxUserName.SelectAll()
            Me.TextBoxUserName.Select()
        End If

        MessageBox.Show(message, _
                        "Login Failed", _
                        MessageBoxButtons.OK, _
                        MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    End If

End Sub``
```

This is the password class I would prefer to use:

```vb
Imports System
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Security.Cryptography
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Imports System.Net.Sockets
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions



Public Class PasswordHash

    Public Const SALT_BYTE_SIZE As Integer = 24
    Public Const HASH_BYTE_SIZE As Integer = 24
    Public Const PBKDF2_ITERATIONS As Integer = 1000

    Public Const ITERATION_INDEX As Integer = 0
    Public Const SALT_INDEX As Integer = 1
    Public Const PBKDF2_INDEX As Integer = 2


    Public Shared Function CreateHash(password As String) As String
        ' Generate a random salt
        Dim csprng As New RNGCryptoServiceProvider()
        Dim salt As Byte() = New Byte(SALT_BYTE_SIZE - 1) {}
        csprng.GetBytes(salt)

        ' Hash the password and encode the parameters
        Dim hash As Byte() = PBKDF2(password, salt, PBKDF2_ITERATIONS, HASH_BYTE_SIZE)
        Return PBKDF2_ITERATIONS + ":" + Convert.ToBase64String(salt) + ":" + Convert.ToBase64String(hash)
    End Function

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Validates a password given a hash of the correct one.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="password">The password to check.</param>
    ''' <param name="correctHash">A hash of the correct password.</param>
    ''' <returns>True if the password is correct. False otherwise.</returns>
    Public Shared Function ValidatePassword(password As String, correctHash As String) As Boolean
        ' Extract the parameters from the hash
        Dim delimiter As Char() = {":"c}
        Dim split As String() = correctHash.Split(delimiter)
        Dim iterations As Integer = Int32.Parse(split(ITERATION_INDEX))
        Dim salt As Byte() = Convert.FromBase64String(split(SALT_INDEX))
        Dim hash As Byte() = Convert.FromBase64String(split(PBKDF2_INDEX))

        Dim testHash As Byte() = PBKDF2(password, salt, iterations, hash.Length)
        Return SlowEquals(hash, testHash)
    End Function

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Compares two byte arrays in length-constant time. This comparison
    ''' method is used so that password hashes cannot be extracted from
    ''' on-line systems using a timing attack and then attacked off-line.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="a">The first byte array.</param>
    ''' <param name="b">The second byte array.</param>
    ''' <returns>True if both byte arrays are equal. False otherwise.</returns>
    Private Shared Function SlowEquals(a As Byte(), b As Byte()) As Boolean
        Dim diff As UInteger = CUInt(a.Length) Xor CUInt(b.Length)
        Dim i As Integer = 0
        While i < a.Length AndAlso i < b.Length
            diff = diff Or CUInt(a(i) Xor b(i))
            i += 1
        End While
        Return diff = 0
    End Function

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Computes the PBKDF2-SHA1 hash of a password.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="password">The password to hash.</param>
    ''' <param name="salt">The salt.</param>
    ''' <param name="iterations">The PBKDF2 iteration count.</param>
    ''' <param name="outputBytes">The length of the hash to generate, in bytes.</param>
    ''' <returns>A hash of the password.</returns>
    Private Shared Function PBKDF2(password As String, salt As Byte(), iterations As Integer, outputBytes As Integer) As Byte()
        Dim pbkdf2__1 As New Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password, salt)
        pbkdf2__1.IterationCount = iterations
        Return pbkdf2__1.GetBytes(outputBytes)
    End Function
End Class
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: What's the problem? Exchange `Me.ValidateCredentials` for `PasswordHash.ValidatePassword(...)`.  Of course, you should adapt the way you generate the hash for storing in the databse (`PasswordHash.CreateHash`)

Comment: Thanks for the reply in my current code I am using System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(TextBoxPassword.Text) so I can see how it is grabbing the user input in the second code I cannot see where it is getting the users password from

Comment: It doesn't. You have to provide both the input and the hash as parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
//Store a password hash:
PasswordHash hash = new PasswordHash("password");
byte[] hashBytes = hash.ToArray();

//Check password against a stored hash
byte[] hashBytes = //read from store.
PasswordHash hash = new PasswordHash(hashBytes);
if(!hash.Verify("newly entered password"))
throw new System.UnauthorizedAccessException();
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please would you add some explanation to your code showing how it solves the problem. This will help others who see your answer in the future